# How to prove this function is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I should prove this is convex:
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \max(\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+20x_3^2-x_1x_2-4x_2x_3+1}~,(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1+x_2+2)^2)$$
If two functions are convex, then [the composition is also convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287716/the-composition-of-two-convex-functions-is-convex). So as we know, [the **$\max$** function is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435464/show-that-max-function-on-mathbb-rn-is-convex); if we can prove the two functions in it are also convex, we are done.
I proved that the second function $$(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1+x_2+2)^2$$ is convex using the second derivative.

The problem I have is with the first one$$\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+20x_3^2-x_1x_2-4x_2x_3+1}$$ proving it using the second derivative is very complex, and I think there is an easier way to prove it.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about theory, but have a bespoke idea that may work. If you can prove that the function is convex when restricted to any *line* in $x_1x_2x_3$ space, then it will be convex. So, start with a line $x_1=a_1+b_1t, x_2=a_2+b_2t, x_3=a_3+b_3t, t\in\mathbb R$. You will get something like $\sqrt{At^2+Bt+C}$ with $A>0$ and the discriminant $B^2-4AC\gt 0$. This should now be tractable via second derivative.

Comment: Also, a very similar problem: [Can you prove that this function is convex? $\sqrt{2x_1^2+3x_2^2+x_3^2+4x_1x_2+7} + (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+1)^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747565/can-you-prove-that-this-function-is-convex-sqrt2x-123x-22x-324x-1x-27)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes. I saw that problem before; the fact is we cannot make this a complete square or a norm as the question you mentioned

Comment: Well, [all eigenvalues are positive](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B1%2C-0.5%2C0%7D%2C%7B-0.5%2C1%2C-2%7D%2C%7B0%2C-2%2C20%7D%7D) so it is a norm. It may be unwieldy to explicitly write the orthogonal transformation, surely, but all that matters is that it *exists*. Also, I don't see a problem in completing the square either.

Comment: Something like $(x_1-\frac{1}{2}x_2)^2+\frac{3}{4}(x_2-\frac{8}{3}x_3)^2+\frac{44}{3}x_3^2+1$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I will post my answer soon,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  [Stinking Bishop](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/700480/stinking-bishop) I think this should be the proof of the convexity:$$\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+20x_3^2-x_1x_2-4x_2x_3+1}$$$$=\sqrt{(x_1-\frac{1}{2}x_2)^2+\frac{3}{4}(x_2-\frac{8}{3}x_3)^2+\frac{44}{3}x_3^2+1}$$
so that's a norm:$$||(x_1-\frac{1}{2}x_2),\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(x_2-\frac{8}{3}x_3),(2\sqrt{\frac{11}{3}}x_3),1||$$
also we know [every norm is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280341/why-is-every-p-norm-convex) so we're done.